# my react application is getting redirected to homepage after refreshing any page . I even used setState(null)

Tags: reactjs

Everything works fine I am getting redirected to homepage after successful login, the problem arises when I refresh the page from any route I am always getting redirected to home page, why is that so?

I checked everything its fine, once  login  can go to  home pages as we no need to login again then when i go to buyer category pages and refresh it, it is redirected to home again

```
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import '../src/App.css'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes,Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import BuyerCategoryPage from './pages/BuyerCategorypage'
import SellerHomepage from "./pages/SellingDetails";
import Profile from './pages/Profile'
import Cycle from './pages/ProductDetails'
import BuyerHomepage from "./pages/BuyerHomepage";
import SellerCategorypage from "./pages/SellerCategorypage";
import {  useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  // const user = true;
  const [user,setUser] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser =  () => {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/login/success', {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        },
      }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
        throw new Error("authentication has been failed")
      }).then(resObject => {
        setUser(resObject.user)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
    getUser();
  }, []);


  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
  
    // Wait for 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={isLoading ? <Splash /> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'} />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={user ? <Home/> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'}/> } />
            <Route path="/auth/login" element={user ? <Navigate to={'/home'} /> : <Login/>} />
            <Route path="/buyercategory" element={user ? <BuyerCategoryPage/> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'}/> } />
            <Route path="/buyerhomepage" element={user ? <BuyerHomepage/> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'}/>} />
            <Route path="/sellercategory" element={user ? <SellerCategorypage/> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'}/>} />
            <Route path="/sellerhomepage" element={user ? <SellerHomepage/> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'}/>} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={user ? <Profile/> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'}/>} />
            <Route path="/productdetails/:productId" element={user ? <Cycle /> : <Navigate to={'/auth/login'} />} />
            
          </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is /auth/login/success

```
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      "success": true,
      "message": "successfull",
      "user":req.user, 
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

user is a temporary variable refresh will reset. please use cookie or Authorize judge login or not.